# Is there a way to tell if a navaid in the plan view of an approach plate is collocated with DME equipment?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, instrument-approaches

If there are DME distances depicted in the plan or profile view of an approach plate, it is usually pretty obvious which navaid they are referenced to. I'm wondering if there is a way to tell definitively if a navaid has DME by some indication within the navaid box depicted in the plan view.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example? What chart provider are you referring to? Otherwise, the symbol used should indicate if it is a VOR/DME, TACAN, VORTAC, or DME-only facility.

Comment: Do you have an example of a navaid depicted on a chart where that information isn't available either on the chart legend or on the depiction itself (i.e. a "DME" notation or a TACAN channel such as "ch 112")? Between those two references, I can't think of a time that DME availability isn't clear, but do you have an example where it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell from inspecting a few plates, approaches use the same symbology as vfr / ifr charts. So a VOR is a hexagon, a VOR/DME is a hexagon inside a rectangle, a TACAN is a kind of 3-lobed thingy.